# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cv::cvtColor

Tags: c++, object, distance

I have downloaded a program from a YouTube video, it should be able to detect a red rectangle and calculate the distance.
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Xl8yWvMPl8)

I've never used C++ so that's why I actually need some help.
The error I get when I launch the console is the following:;

> "OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cv::cvtColor, file C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 3739"

I'm not sure what it means, and I don't know how I should fix it.
I've managed to include all the files and using the correct libraries but it won't work. Personally I don't have a webcam, but I asked a friend of mine, which has one, to try out the program but he gets the same error.

So here is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include "opencv2\imgproc\imgproc_c.h"
#include <fstream>
#include "math.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

Mat img, img_gray, channel[3];
VideoCapture cam(1);
double distance = 0;

//FILE *data;
//data = fopen("data320.csv","a");

cam.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280);
cam.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720);
cam.set(CV_CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB, 1);
namedWindow("Frame", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
while (waitKey(10) != 'a')
{
    cam >> img;
    cvtColor(img, img_gray, COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
    split(img, channel);
    subtract(channel[2], img_gray, img_gray);
    //convertScaleAbs(img, img);
    threshold(img_gray, img_gray, 90, 255, THRESH_BINARY);

    erode(img_gray, img_gray, Mat(), Point(-1, -1), 4);
    dilate(img_gray, img_gray, Mat(), Point(-1, -1), 4);

    vector<vector<Size>> contors;
    vector<Vec4i> heirarcy;
    findContours(img_gray, contors, heirarcy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

    vector<Rect> boundRect(contors.size());
    vector<vector<Point>> contor_poly(contors.size());

    for (int i = 0; i< contors.size(); i++)
    {
        approxPolyDP(Mat(contors[i]), contor_poly[i], 3, true);
        boundRect[i] = boundingRect(Mat(contor_poly[i]));
    }
    int max_index = 0, max_area = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i< boundRect.size(); i++)
    {
        int a = boundRect[i].area();
        rectangle(img, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), Scalar(255, 255, 0), 2, 8, 0);
        if (a > max_area)
        {
            max_area = a;
            max_index = i;
        }
    }
    int confidence = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i< boundRect.size(); i++)
    {
        if ((boundRect[i].x < boundRect[max_index].x + boundRect[max_index].width && boundRect[i].x > boundRect[max_index].x - int(0.1*boundRect[max_index].width)) && (boundRect[i].y > boundRect[max_index].y))
            confidence += 45;

    }
    if (boundRect.size() > 0)
    {
        if (confidence > 99)
            confidence = 0;
        //try{
        //Mat sub_image = Mat(img, Rect(max(boundRect[max_index].x-30, 0), max(boundRect[max_index].y-30, 0), min(int(boundRect[max_index].width*1.75), img.cols - boundRect[max_index].x+30), min(boundRect[max_index].height*3, img.rows - boundRect[max_index].y+30)));
        //imshow("Frame", sub_image);
        //}catch(int e){
        //  cout<<"Error occured"<<endl;
        //}
        rectangle(img, boundRect[max_index].tl(), boundRect[max_index].br(), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2, 8, 0);

        //fprintf(data,"%d , %d , %d\n", boundRect[max_index].width, boundRect[max_index].height, boundRect[max_index].area());
        distance = 8414.7*pow(boundRect[max_index].area(), -0.468);
        cout << distance << " cm." << " Confidence: " << confidence << endl;
        imshow("Frame", img);

    }

    else
        imshow("Frame", img);
}



//fflush(data);
//fclose(data);
cam.release();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check shape of image before calling cvtColor, it work only if image shape greater than 2

```
if(img.size>2)
  cvtColor(img, img_gray, COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
```

Comment: If i add the condition it says: no operator ">" matches these operands

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong because it can't recognize the camera?

Comment: when i add: if(img.size) without using the " > 2" it opens and it starts loading all kinds of different dlls, but then it says "Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000DD28778170"